# QGIS feature subset with WFS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, wfs

I have GeoServer running locally, serving up a large table of vector points stored in Postgres. I have enabled a time dimension on GeoServer, from a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. from QGIS, I connect to the WFS. This all works great.

However I cannot use the feature subset of the layer properties in QGIS. The "Query Builder" button is greyed-out and the text box under "Feature subset" is not editable.

**How can I issue a feature subset query for a WFS in QGIS?** For instance, I want to only display points with a time property within a particular date interval. I can add filters to the query itself, but that is not easy to use compared to the query builder. Is this a GeoServer configuration issue? (I just started up a quick demo using Docker, and changed no GeoServer settings outside of those settings I had to choose when establishing my data store, etc.) I need to be able to subset my features, because the full dataset is around 500,000 records.

EDIT: I can open the attribute table and select features with an expression there, and these points are selected on the map. Its just the properties dialog does not allow me to subset.

EDIT: GeoServer 2.9 (snapshot), PostgreSQL 9.3 and QGIS 2.10 if these matter.

EDIT: Can confirm that what I want to do is possible only with the QGIS WFS version 2.0 plugin, but not the default add WFS dialog...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that QGIS does not have support for WFS 2.0.0 (except through this life-saving plugin: [WFS 2.0 Client](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/wfs20client)). Evidence [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6923), [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#ogc-wfs) (*"Only WFS 1.0.0 is supported. At this time, there have not been many tests against WFS versions implemented in other WFS servers"*), and [here](http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/linz-data-service/guides-and-documentation/using-lds-wfs-in-qgis), as well as my own experience.

However using the 2.0 client allows for subset queries within the properties dialogue. (There's a remaining question about my layer not appearing in the list within that plugin, but that seems to be an unrelated question.)

Comment: Any query in query builder seems to run on what's already retrieved from server, rather than re-query server - this has caught me out